# take someone to do or doing

Tags: grammar

Which is correct between the folloing pairs of sentences?

1. I took my son fishing or I took my son to fish.
2. I took my daughter shopping or I took my daughter to shop.
3. I took my kids seeing a movie or I took my kids to see a movie.

If there is any difference in usuage, please explain the details.

Comment: In (1) and (2) both are correct. But for some reason "I took my kids seeing a movie" sounds wrong to me. Hmm.

Comment: _Take_ is one of the causatives of _go_, and it often shares the selectional constructions of _go_. Note that _go fishing_ is the idiomatic term for the recreational activity, while _go to fish_ is not idiomatic and has to refer to a different situation. Similarly _take X fishing_ and _take X to fish_.

Comment: As for (3), you take your kids to a movie; it's an event, like a party. The "seeing" part is what you do at a movie event.

Comment: You can teach someone to fish, but you don't take them to fish.

Comment: Unless you're taking them to an aquarium. :)

Comment: "I took my son to fish at the lake" is fine. It depends if your interest is in conveying your son (*to*) or doing something with your son (*ing*).

Comment: The 'go fishing' (/ 'go dancing' / 'go carol singing' / 'take X shopping' / 'stand watching' / 'sit knitting') twinning of verbs, where both 'activities' are coincident (contrast 'go and stand') are echoes of the present continuous ('be dancing / singing / shopping ...') which Collins Cobuild terms 'phase structures'. There are articles on ELU covering this.

Comment: Would this not be better Posted in English Language Learners?

Either way, both 'I took my son fishing…'  or '… to fish could be correct, but 'to fish' is unlikely. What were the circumstances?

'I took my daughter to shop' isn't wrong, but it would always need justification.

'I took my kids seeing (anything)…'  could never work. 'I took my kids to see a movie' would always be fine.

Again, why would this not be better Posted in English Language Learners?